# Routing: How to hide action name in url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the MVC default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

whenever the index action is accessed, the url is not showing the action name when the "Index" action is accessed.

I would like to get that behaviour on a different controller, which is retrieving data for a single item. I would like the default action to be named "get" and for this action I would like the url not to display the action name, just the controller and the item id.

I thought that a similar route to the one above, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "item_details",
            "item/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "item", action = "Get" }
            );
```

would do the trick, but it gives me a url like localhost:xxxx/item/Get/152... What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "item_details",
        "item/{id}",
        new { controller = "item", action = "Get" }
        );
```

Comment: Done. Sorry, meant to do it yesterday, but with the minimum time imposed by SO I went home before I got to do it ;o)

Comment: @robasta what if `item` is the name of my controller and I only want to hide specific action

Comment: how to hide controller name from route? any idea?

Comment: @robasta Why I get Not Found error if I type `item/Get/25` where id = 25? Anyway to let the route to accept with and without the action name, `Get`?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the users coming here as in *ASP.NET MVC 5.2 days*, it works when 
  you have  `id = UrlParameter.Optional` added, at least for my case

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "item_details",
          url: "item/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "item", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And if there are more routes in `RouteConfig` class, then move this to the top *of other routes* 
**or** 
You can also do:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "item_details",
               url: "item",
               defaults: new { controller = "item", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Ref: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38279899/1042705)