# MVC How to hide link's Html Attribute for security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I pass a Model value(Id) action to action like this:

Controller part:

```
 return RedirectToAction("SaveAction", "MyController", new { MyId= model.Id});
```

View part:

```
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Another View example:

> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { MyId= Model[i].Id,
>   AnotherId= Model.[i].AnotherId})

And on link bar, it's being showed like this:

```
http://localhost:9151/Controller/Save?Id=180
```

When I change "180" to "181", user can see Id=181's all values related View. It's an important security problem for me and users can not reach other Id values like 181, 182, 183 etc.

How can i pass Id value safely to action to action and how can i not show Id value in browser's link bar?

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: have you try to use route provider in mvc?

Comment: instead of get use post

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. No i haven't. it's a multiple project and i don't wat to change route provider.

Comment: You need to handle the security in the controller. A user can still type `/Controller/Save?Id=181` in the address bar.

Comment: see this question and answer may be helps you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968689/routing-how-to-hide-action-name-in-url

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i'm sorry but i haven't get what you mean.

Comment: @Fatih1453 use form to post value that way user will not be able to change id in url

Comment: You should look into using `AuthorizeAttribute`s and having users with specific roles or own particular items that they are authorised to have access to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @Vap i'll check it out.

Comment: @Pricey That won't stop someone making up a new URL

Comment: This might be useful. I've not tried it yet though : http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html

Comment: @DavidG Why would you want to do that anyway, a user can still change the URL. The point is they should be authorising access to the data that is shown in the request result for that URL.

Comment: @Pricey Take a website that shows a list of employees and I only have access to see my team members, adding `AuthoriseAttribute` will stop anonymous users requesting the page but it won't stop me modifying the URL to get an employee I shouldn't see.

Comment: @DavidG you've lost me, you can create custom authorise attributes in MVC that validate against users and roles in your application, thats why I said "having users with specific roles or own particular items that they are authorised to have access" if the user is not authorised to access that URL they just typed then the error should be handled and redirected to an error controller or something similar to display a not authorised message

Comment: I agree completely with Pricey and Stephen - hiding the ID and pretending that this is somehow security is completely false. At best, if you could somehow hide part of the URL and still visit it (which is not possible without route defaults or action defaults) then it still doesn't provide any security - you need to ensure that users have valid claims to data requested by any URL before returning it to them. Any URL pattern can either be discerned or guessed by the user, or viewed in logs/browser history. Security by obscurity at best.

Comment: If your Delete Action is [HttpGet] users can access toit from url.you must change it to [HttpPost] and call it

Answer (score 2):

[A simple way is encode and decode id.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773148/how-to-encrypt-the-query-string-id-in-mvc4-actionlink)

[More secure way is encrypting id.](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-value-provider-for-encrypted-query-string.html)